# Append to array in UserDefaults

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting

First I import the existing array saved in user defaults in key - array1

```
var savedArray = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "array1") as! [String]
var ns = UserDefaults.standard
```

Then

```
let savedValue = name
```

Then

```
savedArray.append(savedValue!)
```

Then I save it in key - array1

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(savedArray, forKey: "array1")
```

And sync

```
ns.synchronize()
```

However, if I go into another viewcontroller and do this

```
let alreadyShownarray = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "array1") as! [String]
print (alreadyShownarray)
```

Then I get the same array without the appended `savedValue!`

Comment: `UserDefaults.standard.set(array2, forKey: "array1")` You are saving `array2` but never mentioned it. You meant `savedArray`: `UserDefaults.standard.set(savedArray, forKey: "array1")`
? Just error on the quesiton?

Comment: where does ns come from?

Comment: @RaduDiță var ns = UserDefaults.standard

Comment: The array that is returned is a struct or passed by value/copy.  If you made a copy of a drawing, adding detail to the copy won't affect the original.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try removing the object and adding the new one.

```
UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "array1")
UserDefaults.standard.set(savedArray, forKey: "array1")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch the array, assign it to a variable, append your element, then set the object for the same key that you used to fetch.

```
func enqueue(localNotificationModel: LocalNotificationModel) {
    guard let localNotificationJSON = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: localNotificationKey) as? [[String: Any]] else { return }
    var localNotifiactions = localNotificationJSON.compactMap { LocalNotificationModel(json: $0)}
    localNotifiactions.append(localNotificationModel)
    UserDefaults.standard.set(localNotifiactions, forKey: localNotificationKey)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot update the Array directly from NSUserDefault. you have to create a new arrray and assign the existing array from NSUserDefault then you can set that new array to the NSUserDefault one

```
var newArray = [String]() //2.create a new array and assign the UserDefault array1 here

var ns = UserDefaults.standard

let savedArray = ns.array(forKey: "array1") as! [String] //1.this is protected cannot update directly

let savedValue: String = "name" //3. the value you wanted to append

newArray = savedArray //4. just copying the value here

newArray.append(savedValue) //5. appending the new value

ns.set(newArray, forKey: "array1") //6. now the value "name" is saved.

// array1[0] = "your initial value"
// array1[1] = "name"
```